# What is the largest single project (in tonnage) in which an international space cooperative has launched and or constructed in space?

Tags: launch, construction, international-politics, radio-telescope

Science fiction has given us countless examples of international space campaigns (exp: Star Trek's "Federation"). But what's the largest and most active space campaign from Earth and how much (in tonnage) has been launched into or constructed in space under its united flag?

Answer (score 5):

The [International Space Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station), by far. The mass of the station varies with time, but it's around 420 tons It was constructed over the course of about 13 years, although it is still being tweaked today.

Comment: The mass is tracked quite precisely, and posted here: http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/realdata/sightings/SSapplications/Post/JavaSSOP/orbit/ISS/SVPOST.html  Presently 405 metric tons.

Comment: I had always heard that it was somewhat tricky to get the exact mass of the ISS, owing to the large number of cargo supplies/trash disposals, which make keeping track of that mass difficult. Still, it seems it is better known than I had thought.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto There are people whose job it is to know exactly what the mass of the ISS is and how it is distributed.  My desk is maybe thirty yards from one of them.

Comment: It is tricky, and I'm sure it's not known to the precision with which the numbers on the SVPOST page are given, but they ought to be good to within a couple of hundred pounds.  I believe the mass estimates are updated based on measured accelerations from known thrust levels during maneuvers, as well as the obvious tracking of upmass and downmass.

Comment: The question in part is, how accurate is downmass tracked? Not to mention leakage of any kind, or other similar incidents...

Comment: Still fairly accurately.  The returning vehicles still have to have known mass properties, even if they'll only be burning up.  It's necessary to ensure safe departure from ISS.  If the mass and CG aren't known, you could have an inadvertent collision.